# Plugin development template for aurelia custom element/attribute(s)

Tags: templates, plugins, dependency-injection, aurelia, loader

I am trying to write some plugins for aurelia. For example let's say that I am trying to develop a tooltip plugin (which is really a custom attribute) and then publish it on npm store. So I have read a bit about how to publish one and no problem with that. For example by now I have written this:

[sample tooltip package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa-au-md-tooltip)

But now I am encountering project problems. For example by now I have to configure a loader to be able to use DI in this plugin.

So I am asking if is there any plugin developement template for aurelia custom element/attribute(s) that all these configurations and tasks are placed inside? Something like aurelia project template itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I have found an appropriate solution. Before this, I have gathered a template by myself containing desired tasks, babel configuration, folder structures and etc. but at this time I have found that I can have a well written template with the CLI command below:

```
au new component-name --plugin
```

Just like generating a new project but with additional argument `--plugin`.

And thanks to aurelia framework and its CLI for this beneficial template.